# Getting <DIV>'s to vertically hug text contents

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to get a div element to hug the contents as tightly as possible. This works fine for the width by using `display:inline-block`, but the height always has some extra `padding`/ `margin`/ `border`. How do I get the parent div to wrap the text *exactly*? I can get it by judicially choosing `line-height`, but this only works for a particular font and size.

How do I get the red box below to wrap the text as close as possible... for any input font or size?

**Example**:

[image]

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RD8sY/1/), with css code

```
.outer {
    display:block;   
    background:red;
}
.hug {
    font-size:200%;
    margin:0em;
    border:0em;
    padding:0em;
}
```

and html:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="hug">
        <h1>PERFECT FIT</h1>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
    <div class="hug">
        <h2>PERFECT FIT</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS, CCS3 solutions preferred over javascript, unless it isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up getting some decent results with this. If you alter the font size the line-height can stay as needed and hugs pretty darn close... Does it need to be to the pixel exactly?

```
.thisone{
  display:inline-block;   
  background:#09f;
  min-width:1px;
  font-family:arial;
  width:auto;
  font-size:70px;
  line-height:.70em;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/JY9yA/)

Comment: This suffers from the problem I had before, namely that I have to measure the `line-height` to work _exactly_ for _each font_ and _each size_. The moment the font changes (or doesn't load and the fallback font loads), this fails.

Comment: Your update is better, and I'll play with it. Any reason why `.70em` is a magic height? It still breaks if another element is present in it (say a `h1`), but it might have to do.

Comment: The em unit is special in that way that it's relative to the default font size. So putting it at 0.7 is like saying that it should always be 70%, and for your scenario I believe that em is the unit and way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is something I've tried : http://jsfiddle.net/wared/CpZru/. My first attempt (pink) worked only with H2, so, I gave a closer look to this tag's default styles, and noticed that the font size was set to `1.5` (Chrome). Then I used this ratio for my second attempt (blue) : `1 / 1.5 = 0.666...`. Although the result is more reliable, the ratio seems not to be valid with a different font weight (1 pixel overflows the P tag's line) or a different font family (green test).

You could calculate the ratio for each font weight/family since both parameters seem to affect the line height ratio. I'm not able to get something more interesting currently. Hope it can help in some way.

```
<div class="em1">
    <h1>PERFECT FIT</h1>
    <h2>PERFECT FIT</h2>
    <p>PERFECT FIT</p>
</div>
<div class="em67">
    <h1>PERFECT FIT</h1>
    <h2>PERFECT FIT</h2>
    <p>PERFECT FIT</p>
</div>
<div class="em67 arial">
    <h1>PERFECT FIT</h1>
    <h2>PERFECT FIT</h2>
    <p>PERFECT FIT</p>
</div>
```

```css
.em1 {
    line-height: 1em;
}
.em1 * {
    background: pink;
    line-height: inherit;
}
.em67 * {
    background: lightblue;
    line-height: .67em;
}
.arial * {
    font-family: Arial;
    background: lightgreen;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems that both you and Phlume came to the same conclusion (he beat you to it, so I'll accept his). It just seems funny to me that this isn't simple fix - the browser clearly knows the _exact_ width, it should know the height too.

Comment: @Hooked Thanks for the reward, I wasn't even expecting an upvote :) About the browser, it does since (afaik) `font height = css font-size`, but the font size does not necessarily fit with the symbol printed to the screen.

Answer (score -1):

```
.outer {
    display:block;   
    background:red;
    float:left;
    clear:both;
}
.hug {
    font-size:200%;
    margin:0em;
    border:0em;
    padding:0em;
}
.hug h1,
.hug h2 {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    height:1em;
    line-height:1em;
}
```

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but this doesn't work: http://jsfiddle.net/LxrsF/ If you can get it working please post the jsfiddle so I can see what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Is there a reason you are not putting the background colour on the h1, and h2 themselves? Other wise, my next answer is getting closer..

Comment: The putting the background on h1,h2 doesn't solve the problem nor does setting the line-height/height as there is still a significant vertical padding. I mentioned in the question that changing `line-height` was my first attempt.